# Chebyshev Polynomials of $P_3$

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

Solve a special cubic equation $4x^3-3x=a$ by plugging $x=(u+u^{-1})/2$. Note that the equation has a form $P_3(x)=a$.

Comment: I took the liberty of TeXifying your question, and looked for a more descripitive tag. If I mangled it, please say so, and/or try and edit yourself now that you have a small sample about inserting TeX-code (it is autointerpreted in the preview window, so you can experiment).

Comment: I'm not sure that I can follow your question. Are you familiar with the fact that if $x=\cos t$, then $P_n(x)=\cos nt$. In addition to that here you have $u=e^{it}$. Does that help you?